# Waiting for an UI Job to end (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My problem is: When I debug a code like e.g.:

someSpinner.setSelection(0);
someEditText.setEnabled(true);

then I see that the first action is actually executed AFTER the second one. My guess is that the spinner action is put in some kind of asynchronous job that does not start immediately. My goal is to wait until the first action has been completed, and then run the second.
Anyone know how to realize this?

In Eclipse RCP I was solving this similar to the following:

```
    uiJob1.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getResult().isOK()) {
        uiJob2.schedule();
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
    });

    // 2
    uiJob2.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getResult().isOK()) {
        ...
        } else {
        ...
        }
    }
    });

    uiJob1.schedule();
```

Comment: You are thinking about this in the wrong way.  But can't say what the right way is because you haven't said **why** and **what** you are trying to do.  To somehow wait for a UI update to finish though is definitely a flawed design in a multi-threaded, asycnh OOP environment.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is common for Android: you have no guarantee that all the actions will occur in a synchronous mode - aka the order you have executed them into your code - when they are event driven.

I think you should try to add an `OnItemSelectedListener()` listener on your spinner and see if this event is also  catching your action: `someSpinner.setSelection(0);`

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Let me know if this could work.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your quick answer, Paul.

I already have an OnItemSelectedListener on the spinner. Inside that listener, in one case, I am executing someEditText.setEnabled(false). And because the commands are not executed in synchronous mode, the second action of my first post (someEditText.setEnabled(true);) has no effect :-/

I found out that by calling someSpinner.setSelection(0, false); it is being executed before someEditText.setEnabled(true); but I do not want to rely on this "solution"...

Comment: Can you post me some code? I am really interested in this case and would like to try to use getViewTreeObserver().